# While writing records in a flat file using Informatica ETL job, greek characters are coming as boxes

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

While writing records in a flat file using Informatica ETL job, greek characters are coming as boxes.We can see original characters in the database.In session level, we are using UTF-8 encoding.We have a multi language application and need to process Chinese, Russian, Greek,Polish,Japanese etc. characters.Please suggest.

Comment: If this is a one stage etl (unlikely) then its making sure the codepages of your source, target at mapping and session level and character set within the source db are set to the correct encoding (utf-8). If not you'll have to put measures in place to rectify

Answer (score 0):

try to change your page encoding. I also faced this kind of issue. We are using ANSII encoding, hence we created separate integration service with different encoding and file ran successfully.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy option. In session properties, select target flat file then click **set file propeties**. In that you can change the code-page. There you can choose UTF-8. By default it is in ANSII, that's why you are facing this issue.